# How can I make my code return random letters in a grid?

Tags: python, loops, grid, crossword

I'm trying to write a code that will return random letters in a 4 * 4 grid. Here is my attempt so far

So I have created a grid like this

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

using this code:

```
board = ['[]' * 4 ] * 4
for x in board:
    print(x)
```

and now I'm trying to replace each `[]` with a letter in it, like `[A]`

and I tried to do it by implementing this piece of code

```
import random
import string
for x in row:
    print(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
```

but the code prints this out..

```
s
K
U
J
l
e
X
s
```

instead of a grid, which I expected to be like this...

```
[A][D][F][T]
[S][D][A][E]
[R][V][B][S]
[O][P][L][K]
```

what should I change in my code to ensure the output is like the grid mentioned right above?

Here is my full code btw..

```
import random
import string

board = ['[]' * 4 ] * 4
for row in board:
    print(row)

for x in row:
    print(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
```

Comment: Format the output of each row after generating the random characters

Comment: @Nutnicha check the answer if work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import random
import string

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        print( '['+random.choice(string.ascii_letters)+']',end='' )
    print()
```

Output:

```
[I][j][p][r]
[O][C][H][x]
[y][a][e][x]
[V][z][Y][r]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in this way:

```
board = []
row = []
for i in range(4):
    row.clear()
    for j in range(4):
        row.append('[' + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + ']')
    board.append(row.copy())

for row in board:
    print(''.join(row))
```

Output:

```
[Q][E][v][Z]
[w][w][Q][R]
[R][l][c][J]
[p][F][S][M]

Process finished with exit code 0
```